# Python парсинг. Страница не отображает нужные элементы

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

Хочу спарсить некоторые игры вот здесь https://stopgame.ru/topgames?year_end=2022&p=1 , проблема в том, что html код который я получаю в программе не тот , который наблюдаю на сайте ,  мне нужно спарсить количество оценок игр помимо всего прочего.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот этот класс, который мне нужен есть тут, а в переменной

```
page_html=requests.get(url=URL+str(page), headers=headers)
```

его почему то нет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

```
URL = 'https://stopgame.ru/topgames?year_end=2022&p='
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}
for page in  range(1,1+1):
    page_html=requests.get(url=URL+str(page), headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page_html.content, 'lxml')
    ranking=soup.find('button',class_="_rating_67304_39").text.replace('.','')

    print(soup)
```

Comment: А это что по вашему print(soup.find('button',class_="_rating_67304_39")) ==><button class="_rating_67304_39" data-auth="true" type="button"><svg style="color: rgb(var(--green))" viewbox="0 0 576 512"><use href="#fa/star"></use></svg>5.0</button> ?

Comment: Это рейтинг игры средне арифметический  , мне количество оценок нужно вытащить ещё, сколько пользователей оценку поставили, по моему на скриншоте показано это

Comment: На сайте две таблицы.  Одна плиткой все игры, без количества оценок, только рейтинг, вторая со всеми данными. В коде загpужается таблица плиткой. Вам нужно найти механизм переключения этих таблиц.

Comment: Спасибо, а как это можно сделать? Тут xhr не причём? Или прописать post для авторизации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.Session()
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
                         '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}
session.headers.update(headers)
page = 1
url = f'https://stopgame.ru/topgames?year_end=2022&p={page}'
response = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
token = soup.find(attrs={'name': "csrf-token"})['content']
print(list(soup.find(attrs={'data-key': True}).stripped_strings))
# ['5.0']
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------401666322440753488502896157079',
    'x-csrf-token': token,
}
login = 'bumb'
password = 'vIAzGvV'
data = f'-----------------------------401666322440753488502896157079\r\n' \
       f'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="login"\r\n\r\n{login}\r\n' \
       f'-----------------------------401666322440753488502896157079\r\n' \
       f'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"\r\n\r\n{password}\r\n' \
       f'-----------------------------401666322440753488502896157079--\r\n'

response = session.post('https://stopgame.ru/ajax/auth/login', headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.json()['error'] if not response.json()['success'] else "Тук-тук")
# Тук-тук
response = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
print(list(soup.find(attrs={'data-key': True}).stripped_strings))
# ['5.0']
cookies = {'_sg-identity': 'aaee3c3d98ffa628619cb118d2f926df47517898b3061349db86842866fabaa'
                           '9a%3A2%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A12%3A%22_sg-identity%22%3Bi%3A1%3Bs%3A52'
                           '%3A%22%5B652577%2C%227a131397573f30fc3f303dccf05108ac%22%2C31536000%5D%22%3B%7D', }
response = session.get(f'{url}&grid_type=list', cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
print(list(soup.find(attrs={'data-key': True}).stripped_strings))
# ['Cube Escape Collection', 'Платформы', 'Android', '|', 'Mac', '|', 'PC', 'Жанр', 'неизвестно',
#  'Дата выхода', '14 октября 2020', 'Мой статус', '+13', 'Уведомления', '5.0', '7 оценок', 'Моя оценка', 'Очистить']
```

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем случае проблема заключается в то, что-бы собрать количество оценок с страницы игры вам сперва необходимо получить ссылки на каждую игру, затем пройтись по каждой странице с игрой и уже там вытащить количество оценок. Вот код, который поможет Вам это сделать:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://stopgame.ru/topgames?year_end=2022&p='
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.72 Safari/537.36'}
for page in  range(1,1+1):
    page_html=requests.get(url=URL+str(page), headers=headers)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page_html.content, 'lxml')
    href = soup.find_all('a', class_="_card_67304_1")
    for h in href:
        game_page_url=f'https://stopgame.ru{h.get("href")}'
        game_page_html=requests.get(game_page_url, headers)
        game_soup=BeautifulSoup(game_page_html.content, 'lxml')
        ranking=game_soup.find('span',class_="_users-rating__count_sh7r2_1").text.replace('.','')
        print(ranking)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое,  но ссылки есть по той же ссылке которую я скинул,на скриншоте видны они,  просто когда через мобильный открываете аддаптивная вёрстка их не отображает. Это не  в xhr проблема?

Comment: Не знаю, у меня отображает плиткой все игры, без количества оценок, только рейтинг.

Comment: При чём в том классе который Вы ищите class_="_rating_67304_39" вообще находится SVG с рейтингом.

Comment: Да класс который я нашёл, это для других целей, это для рейтинга. А если плитками отображается... Хм, попробуйте через компьютер открыть, у меня разрешение 1920 на 1080 , когда через комп открываю. У Вас видимо адаптивная вёрстка на меньшее разрешение срабатывает

Comment: Я с десктопа смотрю и разрешение у меня то же. А вы пробовали запустить код, который я Вам отправил, он не решает Вашей проблемы?

Comment: Я понял в чём проблема того, что хотите получить Вы. Если вы авторизованы то вам доступно изменение отображения список или плитка. Запрос такой: 'https://stopgame.ru/topgames?year_end=2022&p=1&grid_type=list', но если вы не авторизовались, то у вас отображается плитка, а в том коде HTML отсутствует отображение количества оценок. Вам или надо написать механизм авторизации (возможно использовать Selenium), или воспользоваться кодом из ответа. Выбор за вами. Удачи!

Comment: Ваш код работает, спасибо, просто хочется подгружать непосредственно с главной страницы, я думаю производительность быстрее будет, а если переходить на каждую страницу, парсить её и вытаскивать значения это займёт больше времени. Ну это уже вопрос перфекционизма) Спасибо большое)

Comment: Post авторизация поможет как думаете?

Comment: Ну, тут уже как Вам удобно. Почитайте про способы реализации подобных запросов и реализуйте тот который покажется вам наиболее приемлемым для Вашей задачи. Я бы использовал Selenium скорее всего в этом случае. Вот пример авторизации: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cInWsj199Kk]

Comment: спасибо, попробую